# Irregularity in fetching the details with array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a table structure and I am trying to fetch the movie_id from moviedb.org before insert query .

[image]

here is the part of the code

```
      $movie_name = $arrTitle[0];

    $apiKey = '30f44b6ef9472d414e50d2acaa058b60';
    $url = simplexml_load_file("http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1/Movie.search/en/xml/30f44b6ef9472d414e50d2acaa058b60/"$movie_name"");
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
    $movies = $xml->movies->movie;
    $images = $xml->xpath("//image");
   foreach ($movies as $movie){
        $arrMovie_id = $movie->id;
    }
    foreach ($images as $image){
    $attr = $image->attributes();
     if($image['size'] == "thumb" && $image['type']=="poster"){       
        $images= $image['url'];
        }
    }
    $arrStr = explode(':',$htmlShowTime);
    $release = substr($arrStr[3],0,strlen($arrStr[3])-8);
    $director = substr($arrStr[5],0,strlen($arrStr[5])-11); 

    $sql_movie = "insert into jos_movie(movie_name,language,cast,movie_release,director,rating,rating_count,movie_ids,image)values('$movie_name','null','$cast','$release','$director',250,230,'$arrMovie_id','$images')";
    //echo $sql.'<br>';
   // echo $sql_movie;

    mysql_query($sql_movie);
```

As you see the code I am trying to get movie_id from `$url` but getting the 0 and in some case "Array' in image fields

for example for first movie "Go Goa Gone"

The URL is `http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1/Movie.search/en/xml/30f44b6ef9472d414e50d2acaa058b60/%22Go%20Goa%20Gone%22`

and it should fetch id and image

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
  <opensearch:Query searchTerms="&quot;Go+Goa+Gone&quot;"/>
  <opensearch:totalResults>1</opensearch:totalResults>
  <movies>
    <movie>
      <score>42.34326</score>
      <popularity>3</popularity>
      <translated>true</translated>
      <adult>false</adult>
      <language>en</language>
      <original_name>Go Goa Gone</original_name>
      <name>Go Goa Gone</name>
      <alternative_name></alternative_name>
      <type>movie</type>
      <id>191562</id>
      <imdb_id>tt2436516</imdb_id>
      <url>http://www.themoviedb.org/movie/191562</url>
      <votes>0</votes>
      <rating>0.0</rating>
      <certification>NR</certification>
      <overview>A rave party off the coast of Goa, goes horrifyingly and hilariously wrong when the island is overrun with zombies.</overview>
      <released>2013-05-10</released>
      <images>
        <image type="poster" url="http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w92/cSDvyWmh7rSD7WtSoXScVw3GDnD.jpg" size="thumb" width="92" height="133" id="51880dd7760ee3144531d0b9"/>
        <image type="poster" url="http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w154/cSDvyWmh7rSD7WtSoXScVw3GDnD.jpg" size="w154" width="154" height="222" id="51880dd7760ee3144531d0b9"/>
        <image type="poster" url="http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w185/cSDvyWmh7rSD7WtSoXScVw3GDnD.jpg" size="cover" width="185" height="267" id="51880dd7760ee3144531d0b9"/>
        <image type="poster" url="http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w342/cSDvyWmh7rSD7WtSoXScVw3GDnD.jpg" size="w342" width="342" height="493" id="51880dd7760ee3144531d0b9"/>
        <image type="poster" url="http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w500/cSDvyWmh7rSD7WtSoXScVw3GDnD.jpg" size="mid" width="500" height="721" id="51880dd7760ee3144531d0b9"/>
        <image type="poster" url="http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/original/cSDvyWmh7rSD7WtSoXScVw3GDnD.jpg" size="original" width="810" height="1168" id="51880dd7760ee3144531d0b9"/>
        <image type="backdrop" url="http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w300/mjxJT7skpStIGyp1bAe7XCsTVEN.jpg" size="thumb" width="300" height="169" id="51880e1f760ee3059e36a012"/>
        <image type="backdrop" url="http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w780/mjxJT7skpStIGyp1bAe7XCsTVEN.jpg" size="poster" width="780" height="439" id="51880e1f760ee3059e36a012"/>
        <image type="backdrop" url="http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w1280/mjxJT7skpStIGyp1bAe7XCsTVEN.jpg" size="w1280" width="1280" height="720" id="51880e1f760ee3059e36a012"/>
        <image type="backdrop" url="http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/original/mjxJT7skpStIGyp1bAe7XCsTVEN.jpg" size="original" width="1280" height="720" id="51880e1f760ee3059e36a012"/>
      </images>
      <version>1</version>
      <last_modified_at>2013-05-06 20:14:04 UTC</last_modified_at>
    </movie>
  </movies>
</OpenSearchDescription>
```

Here is the var_dump for `$movie_name`

```
string(12) "Go Goa Gone "
string(6) "Gippi "
string(19) "Shootout at Wadala "
string(23) "Lucky Di Unlucky Story "
string(11) "Aashiqui 2 "
```

Where I am wrong in the code for this irregularity?

Comment: You're changing your question and you have removed first image and duplicated it with last/below image? What do you want? In your specified `URL` I am getting `<id>191562</id>` as movie id? Is it correct?

Comment: @NullVoid someproblem with image host . I have fixed the images

Comment: Please post an actual snippet of the relevant returned XML, rather than an image from your browser.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I added the xml of one of the movie

Comment: I am getting proper `id`

Comment: @NullVoid if you do it with single movie you wiil get. But when I run the script in cron Job, in result I am getting the values as shown in screenshot with `0` and `Array` in DB instead of values. It might be improper use of array or for each loop . I have edited the mainpost to show the `var_dump` of `$movie_name` also

Comment: Can you give `URL` from which I can see multiple movie listing? So that can get more idea.

Comment: @NullVoid Actually I am crawling some page to get the movie names and the cinemas running them . From that I make an array for all movie names. Rest all values are inserted properly in DB except the image and id. I dont have any such `URL` to show the movie names. :( Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute like this in for loop where multiple images are found. I created list of multiple movie listing in XML file and test below code.

```
//$movies = $xml->movies;
    $movies = $xml->xpath("//movies/descendant::movie");
    //echo "<pre>";print_r($movies);die;
    //$images = $xml->xpath("//image");
    foreach ($movies as $movie){
        echo $arrMovie_id = $movie->id;
        $images = $movie->xpath("//image");
        //echo "<pre>";print_r($images);
            $imageUrl = array();
        foreach ($images as $image){
            if($image['size'] == "thumb" && $image['type']=="poster"){       
                $imageUrl[] = $image['url'];
            }
        }

        //then you need to implode $imageUrl array to string so that you can add multiple found image urls
        $imageUrl = implode(",", $imageUrl);

        $arrStr = explode(':',$htmlShowTime);
        $release = substr($arrStr[3],0,strlen($arrStr[3])-8);
        $director = substr($arrStr[5],0,strlen($arrStr[5])-11); 

        $sql_movie = "insert into jos_movie(movie_name,language,cast,movie_release,director,rating,rating_count,movie_ids,image)values('$movie_name','null','$cast','$release','$director',250,230,'$arrMovie_id','$imageUrl')";
        //echo $sql.'<br>';
        echo $sql_movie;

        //mysql_query($sql_movie);
        echo "<hr/>";
    }
```

Edit:
imageUrl is created as array in code
$imageUrl in sql query instead of $images (it is array of XML so will not be used)

From above code I am able to insert multiple movies in table see image below
[image: multiple movie list]

Comment: only one movie got inserted :( and that too with image `Array` id was correct

Comment: Did you noticed my updated code than your once? I am fetching multiple movies and based on that one movie I am selecting their images and put those Image Urls in $imageUrl and afterwards creating string with multiple Image Urls per Movie.

Comment: But the same didnt worked for the multiple movies . It worked well for fetching the correct for single movie But when i used you code in my file, it fetched only one movie

Comment: with `$movies = $xml->xpath("//movies/descendant::movie");
    echo "<pre>";print_r($movies);die;` you will get all movies from your return XML.

Comment: yeah I getting the mvoies but while insert I can only see 1 movie inserted, rest wont show up in DB

Comment: See above image of insertion of multiple movies in table. For test purpose I have created two fields `id` and `movieimage`. I could successfully inserted movies.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29786/discussion-between-deonia-and-nullvoid)